# Response time loading is not correct

Tags: gatling

i can record the simulation through Gatling and able to run the simulation, but i am getting less load time compared to actual UI (User Interface) when generating the reports.

In my case actual load time when i click on some button(one request,it internally loads some data) on UI is almost 3 to 4 mins, but in reports it will show 300 ms...

i can clicked the button then it will take 2 to 4 minutes after that it open one excel, this during  time not coming the reports, the reports giving time 300 or 360 ms.
the button url placed  script in scala and run again but it gives wrong loading time(360 ms)

Thanks in advance,

any suggestions are helpful to me.

Comment: We can't help you without more information/details on the request that is launched by our UI (the one that is long) and how it is translated in Gatling script. Comparing the two might help us understand the inconsistency.

Comment: Also, Gatling is not a browser, so it doesn't parse HTML and load your DOM, run your javascript, apply your CSS, etc and draw your page. So don't misunderstand HTTP response time (what you would see in Google Chrome dev tool Network panel) and global page load time.